# Can I get an app for free if I already purchased it on the same account, but on a different computer?

Tags: mac-appstore

I bought the Xcode app from Apple's Mac App Store last night on a computer which I ended up returning. I now have a new Mac. After logging into the App Store, I am asked to repurchase the app.

Should I do it? Will it know that the app has already been purchased on this account? Is there a way to re-download it instead of repurchasing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you download the same app off of the same account it will be redownloaded for free without charging your account again. The same goes for apps on the iOS App Store.

Comment: No problem, @mac! Glad to help!

Comment: @mac: Just to let you know, if you didn't know this already, if this fixed your problem please click the green checkmark next to my answer so that others that find this question will know how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Goto **Purchased** tab of **App Store** and click **install**

[image: Goto purchased tab of "App Store" and click "install"]

I don't know how to embed image in a comment so posting a reply.